# mysql dump of table limit 100

Tags: mysql

I want to take a dump of a database, but the condition is to have only 100 records from each table in the DB?

Answer (score 9):

I found a small hack for doing that in the [MySQL manual (comment)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#c9796):

```
mysqldump -u [username] -p [dbname] {--opt} --where="true limit 100" > dump.sql
```

Comment: That's hideous and hilarious.  Well-played.  And here I was writing a script!

Comment: People can be really creative in finding solutions :D
Like that proverb, all roads lead to Rome.

Comment: I'm starting to believe that in shell every problem can be solved in one line.

Comment: It's practically an SQL injection vulnerability of mysqldump CLI exploited for the good :D Well done